# Detect when new sim is inserted in device

Tags: android

In my Android application I want to detect if a new sim is inserted (any sim other than the previous sim) in the device.

How can I do that?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ since the duplicate question you linked has been closed as "not a question", it is likely to get deleted, so I don't think it is reasonable to close this question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @DavidWasser Just FYI, if a question is a duplicate target, it can't be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to:
android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED

This broadcast will trigger everytime user inserts a SIM card.
You have to handle things as the way you wanted with given extras:

> Intent: android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED with extras: ss = LOCKED, reason = PIN
>   Intent: android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED with extras: ss = READY, reason = null
>   Intent: android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED with extras: ss = IMSI, reason = null
>   Intent: android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED with extras: ss = LOADED, reason = null

And then discover if sim card is new checking if TelephonyManager.getSubscriberId().
SubId means the entry that SIM card had by the time it was first inserted on a given device.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it is. It is conected to information given within SIM card itself.

Comment: Yes, it is. Every time a new SIM is inserted on SIM tray, a new subId is generated.
Please, do not make confusions with slotId which is 0 or 1 based of SIM tray position for dual SIM.